# Can't set value arraylist when use Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to set value in arraylist with call api when user click item but I have some problem when I use Recyclerview and when I change to use Listview is work! (But I want to use Recyclerview)

I get error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

and in line

> timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().get(position).setVote(Integer.parseInt(vote));

but When I change to Listview is not error

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) lay_custom_center_post_topic.findViewById(R.id.lv_poll_feed);

 AdapDetailTopicPoll adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(timelineFeedListModels.get(i).getPost().getPoll());
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
            adapDetailTopicPoll.notifyDataSetChanged();

            new_position = i;


 public void sendVodePoll(final int position, String poll_id,final int new_position) {

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String URL = "xxxx/xx";
        params.put("poll_id", poll_id);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> pollBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean>();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String vote = null;
                String poll_id=null;
                String status_vote=null;
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                try {
                    List<TopicVoteModel> topicVoteModels = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0 ; i<response.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        vote = jsonObject.getString("vote");
                        topicVoteModels.add(gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), TopicVoteModel.class));
                    }

                    boolean new_status_vote = Boolean.parseBoolean(status_vote);

                    timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().get(position).setVote(Integer.parseInt(vote)); ////line to error 
                    timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().get(position).setStatus_vote(new_status_vote);

                    for (ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean pollBean : timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll()){
                        pollBeanArrayList.add(pollBean);
                    }
                    for (int i=0 ; i<pollBeanArrayList.size() ; i++){

                    }

            AdapDetailTopicPoll adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(pollBeanArrayList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
            adapDetailTopicPoll.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and my adapter

```
public class AdapDetailTopicPoll extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapDetailTopicPoll.MyViewHolder> {

    SearchDetailFragment searchDetailFragment = new SearchDetailFragment();
    Context context;
    private List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> poll = new ArrayList<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean>();

    public AdapDetailTopicPoll( List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> poll ){
        this.poll = poll;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_profile_feed_topic_poll,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tx_poll.setText(""+poll.get(position).getName());
        if (poll.get(position).isStatus_vote()==false){
            holder.img_vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.vote_t_1);
            holder.tx_count_vote.setText(""+poll.get(position).getVote());

        }else {
            holder.img_vote.setImageResource(R.drawable.vote_t_2);
            holder.tx_count_vote.setText(""+poll.get(position).getVote());

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return poll.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tx_poll,tx_count_vote;
        public ImageView img_vote;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tx_poll = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_poll);
            tx_count_vote = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_count_vote);
            img_vote = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_vote);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ProfileFragment.poll_id = String.valueOf(poll.get(getLayoutPosition()).getId());
                    searchDetailFragment.sendVodePoll(getLayoutPosition(),ProfileFragment.poll_id,SearchDetailFragment.new_position);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

is problem from I set OnClick in adapter?

How to fix it?

my model

```
public static class PollBean {

            private int id;
            private int timeline_id;
            private String name;
            private int vote;
            private String created_at;
            private String updated_at;
            private boolean status_vote;

            public PollBean(int id, boolean status_vote, String name, int vote) {
                this.id=id;
                this.status_vote=status_vote;
                this.name=name;
                this.vote=vote;


            }

            public boolean isStatus_vote() {
                return status_vote;
            }

            public void setStatus_vote(boolean status_vote) {
                this.status_vote = status_vote;
            }

            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public int getTimeline_id() {
                return timeline_id;
            }

            public void setTimeline_id(int timeline_id) {
                this.timeline_id = timeline_id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public int getVote() {
                return vote;
            }

            public void setVote(int vote) {
                this.vote = vote;
            }

            public String getCreated_at() {
                return created_at;
            }

            public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
                this.created_at = created_at;
            }

            public String getUpdated_at() {
                return updated_at;
            }

            public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
                this.updated_at = updated_at;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can yo show PollBean model class as well?

Comment: @ArjunGurung i edited ,please check for me. (If I use listview is work ,and same code)

Comment: I could not get your error but error in `timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().get(position).setVote(Integer.parseInt(vote));` throwing `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0 ` , size is 0 means either timelineFeedListModels size is 0 or `timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll()` size is 0. Debug and try it.

Comment: I try debut this line is show not error , or this problem from call adapter repeat ?

Comment: Try to simplify your adapter by sending only PollBean list instead of sending all bulk data.

Comment: @ArjunGurung I sent only PollBean

Comment: Can you add your activity class as well?

Comment: @ArjunGurung i use Fragment

Comment: Then your fragment class.

Comment: add your fragment class ? sorry my english is not good

Comment: Fragment class holding recycleview.

Comment: I decare this , my problem is when user click item in recyclerview is error

Comment: When user clicks item in recycle view it will send position and new position and call sendVodePoll and these position are used in  `timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().get(position).setVote(Integer.parseInt(vote));`. So i think position is working fine problem might be in new_position. Try to print the size of timelineFeedListModels

Comment: @ArjunGurung new_position is correct! i checked

Comment: Print these value before error line `timelineFeedListModels.size()` and `timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().size()`

Comment: line error is change to this line print `timelineFeedListModels.get(new_position).getPost().getPoll().size()` and `timelineFeedListModels.size()` =0

Comment: @ArjunGurung Ummm ,but when I use listview is no problem

Comment: If size are 0 then there are no data and no idea about the listview. All i could do is this much. Add your file project in git and i could help to debug it.

Comment: ok I try sent List<ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean> from adpter is work but I get new error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
` in line `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Replace `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` with `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());`

Comment: it's not error ,but i get new error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(andr‌​oid.support.v7.widge‌​t.RecyclerView$Layou‌​tManager)'` in line `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);`

Comment: recycleView is not initialized, check whether you have called `findViewById ` for recycleView or not if yes then check is it being called before `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);`

Comment: I set `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_poll_feed);` get error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Check id of recycle view.

Comment: yes it's true!!